# LINQ to SQL not storing unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, linq-to-sql

I have had a really good look at the internet for this problem and I just draw a blank as everything that is suggested is already in place.

I have the following code:

```
if (docid == 155)
{
    docbody = "安全工作";

}



var matchedContentBody = (from cb in dc.GetTable<tbl_content_body>()
                              where cb.c_id == docid

                          select cb).SingleOrDefault();

try
{
    matchedContentBody.contentBody = docbody;
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

The field contentBody is (and has always been) nvarchar(max).  When I read this data back, on a webpage with charset utf-8, I just see ????

As I understand it the Unicode field type negates any need for stating that it is Unicode data.

Any guidance in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your dbml file to ensure that the type is `nvarchar`?

Comment: Yes, the dbml says:  [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_contentBody", DbType= "NVarChar(max)", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]

Comment: If I create a really simple classic ASP page (utf-8 charset) with raw sql on it and a text area for the data, I can save the data to the database and display it back correctly. So I think the field on the DB can handle the Unicode. The application I am struggling with is a windows form app (just built as a desktop utility for importing data)

Comment: Have you set a font capable of showing your characters for your text box?

Comment: Try using a `RichTextBox` instead.

Comment: The simple classic asp app that I used to edit the data after trying the failing c# app can display the characters without issue when put in through that form. When reading the same data that is input through LINQ,  (and also on the website that this data is for) it just displays the ??? I think the issue is the data going through linq. I did wonder about specifying it as Unicode somehow (to make sure) but I don't know how to do that in LINQ

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who has this same problem... my solution was to kind of cast the string data as Unicode. Don't ask me why, but it actually worked. Before I run the LINQ update statement in my code, I do this to the string data:

```
docbody = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docbody));
```

Comment: That's really hard to read. Use `System.Text.Encoding.` to access the static members of the base class. It would eliminate the redundant mention of UTF8, too. So, `Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docbody))`. Now, we can see the very suspicious use of `Encoding.Default`. (I'm still noodling on that.)